# Using a same phone no in WhatsApp business cloud Api and in business app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I am integrating whatsapp graph api/whatsapp cloud api in my webapplication/crm.
where I need to send text message or document to the customers and return response from the customers. which will be actioned from my customized crm.
and i also want to access whatsapp business app with the same phone no which i am actually using now.
So is it possible to access the same for both situation with a single phone No.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow cannot answer customer support questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745). Please consider contacting customer support for the company in question with your issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it is not possible to use the same phone number on both **Whatsapp Business API** and **Whatsapp Business APP**. It is also said that you need new phone number on the API, that have never been used on a Business APP before.

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/phone-numbers

Comment: If I want to use my number for the WhatsApp business app. and there might be a few cases like sending invoices, I want to use my APIs. this is not possible as per the docs. any walkaround or any other ways for this use case where the main use is for the app but using APIs for some specific use?